# how do I check email validaton?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I make wizard on click next button not check validate email using regular expression. 
I have use switch case first blank input to show the error otherwise go to next step and after add email input value wrong to not check email this value in Reg how to solve this problem.

```
<form>
  <div class="form-main">
    <div class="form-input">
      <input type="text" id="fname" placeholder="First Name">
      <p id="error"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-input">
      <input type="text" id="lname" placeholder="Last Name">
      <p id="error"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-input">
      <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
      <p id="error"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-input">
      <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
      <p id="error"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-btn">
      <button type="button" id="prev" onClick="prevBtn(this);">prev</button>
      <button type="button" id="next" onClick="nextBtn(this);">next</button>
      <button type="submit" id="submit">submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

First I make variable for RegEx in make a function `emailValidate` name and in this function take a variable `mailFormate` this return text email. This function used in switch case in take a condition input value blank if show error and otherwise check input type text and email but email is blank if show error when add email format wrong to not check the RegEx skip the next step how to solve this problem.

```
    $(window).on('load',function(){
        $('.form-main > .form-input:nth-child(1)').addClass('open');
        $('.form-main > .form-input:not(".open")').addClass('close').hide();    
    });

    var $div = $('.form-input');
    var submits = $('#submit').css('display','none');
    index = 0;

    function updateStatus(a){
        $div.eq(index).removeClass('current').addClass('close').hide();
        index += a; 
        $div.eq(index).addClass('current').removeClass('close').show();

        $('#next').toggle((index !==$div.length-1));
        $('#prev').toggle(index !== 0); 

        if(index == ($div.length - 1)){
            submits.toggle(index !== 0);
        }else{
            submits.hide();
            }
    }

    var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    var error = document.getElementById('error');

    var regEx = {
        emailValidate : function emailValidate(email){
        var mailFormate = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
            return mailFormate.test(email);
        }
    }


    function validation(){
        var inputValue = $('input:visible').val();
        var inputType = $(input).attr('type');  

        if(inputValue !== ''){  
        switch(inputType){
            case 'text' :{
                updateStatus(+1);
            }

            case 'email' :{
                var email = regEx.emailValidate(inputValue);
                    if(!email){
                        error.innerHTML = "please enter valid mail";
                        return false;
                    }else{
                        error.innerHTML = "valid";
                        updateStatus(+1);
                    }
                    break;
                }
                default : '';
            }

        }else{
            $('input:visible').next().html("please enter the value");
            }
    }

    function nextBtn(){
        validation();
    }

    function prevBtn(){
        updateStatus(-1);
        error.innerHTML = '';
    }
```

Comment: you can set the pattern attribute in the input tag right ?

Comment: Yes right mailFormate is email pattern.

Comment: `<input type="email">` checks for email validation on click of "submit" and will show corresponding error if email is not valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.3/css/bootstrapValidator.min.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.3/js/bootstrapValidator.min.js"> </script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/1000hz-bootstrap-validator/0.11.5/validator.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form data-toggle="validator" role="form"> 
 
                                <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                                    <label for="Email" class="control-label"><b>Email</b></label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="umail"  data-minlength="5" placeholder="Email" name="umail" pattern="^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$"  required>
                                    <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                </div>
                            <input type="submit">
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

try this. this is done using bootstrap validator plug-in

Comment: ok i try but client say not use bootstrap.Thank you for help me

Comment: anyways my answer helped you or not ?

Comment: please vote for my answer,by clicking the up arrow left side of my answer

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form>
 Email: <input type="email" name="country_code" pattern="^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$" >
  <input type="submit">
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

try this,

Comment: this will auto generate error the warning until the user enter the email in the correct format, try it good luck :)

Comment: if it is working for you please vote for my answer. than you :)

Comment: But submit button show last step and last step is password so before check email validation his valid so go to next step and i make only javascript using regular expression using function show above js code.

Comment: are you familiar with bootstrap ?

Comment: yes I have familiar bootstrap.but In project not used bootstrap.

Comment: ok i will show you something which is little bit more interesting